# Solving a linear differential equation using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm trying to solve the following problem

> $x'+x=f(t)$, $x'(0)=1$
>
> $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & \mbox{if } t\in [0,1[ \\ 1, & \mbox{if } t\in[1,+\infty[\end{cases}$

I have no doubts about how to take the Laplace transform of the 1st member of my equation. However I have no idea on how to treat the 2nd member $f(t)$?
Can someone give me a hint? Then I can solve the equation and invert my Laplace transformation without doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is $$\int_0^1 0dt+\int_1^\infty e^{-ts}dt = \dfrac{e^{-s}}{s}\,, s>0.$$

Or if you have learned basic manipulation of Laplace transform, then $$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \mathcal{L}\{u_1(t)\cdot 1\} = e^{-s}\mathcal{L}\{1\} = \dfrac{e^{-s}}{s}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It looks like $f(t)=u(t-1)$ where $u$ is the unit step function, the laplace transform of $u(t-a)$ is $\frac {e^{-as}}{s}$

Comment: Hi Guacho! What if my first interval was pi to 2pi and my second was 0 to pi and 2pi to infinity. What if I had 3 intervals? How do I know what transformations I need to apply to the Heaviside function?

Comment: @GrangerObliviate do you mean that $f(t)=1 \ \forall t \in [\pi, 2\pi]$ and zero elsewhere?

Comment: Yes! But I think I got how to do it now. It's just subtract two Heavisides

Comment: @GrangerObliviate yes, then $f(t)=u(t-\pi)-u(t-2\pi)$, just apply the Laplace Transform and because of its linearity, you can use the information given in my answer about $u(t-a)$